# Designing $3$-bit input/output function

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra, cryptography

I want to find a function(S-box) (if it exists) such that $S(x) \not = x$ for every input $x$ and also changing each single bit causes at least two bit changes. This means that if we take $S(000) = abc$, the value of $S(001)$ should be $a'b'c$, $ab'c'$, $a'bc'$ or $a'b'c'$. Intuitively, putting the first condition aside, it seems that we can't have such a function because there aren't enough possibilities to cover all the possible single bit changes. I mean we have only $8$ outputs but many more single bit changes can happen. $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
100 @>>> 000 @>>> 001 @>>> 101\\
@V  V V @VV    V @VVV @VVV\\
110 @>>> 010 @>>> 011 @>>> 111
\end{CD}$$
How can we formally prove that such a function doesn't exist? Also what can be said about functions with $m$-bit input and $n$-bit output that have this property? I mean is there any general condition for existence of a function such that every $t$ bits changes of the input leads to at least $s$ bits changes of the output where $t\le m$ and $s\le n$?

Comment: [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) ?

Comment: @GCab Thanks but my question is different. The property that I mentioned is "changing each single bit causes at least two bit changes".

Comment: Do you need an invertible one?

Comment: @kelalaka When $m = n$, I think it should be invertible so that the desirable property can hold. In the case $m \not = n$, it can't be invertible.

Comment: If you don't need an invertible then you can simply design one very easily. This is of course one of the necessities for a secure SBox design.

Comment: @kelalaka Can you elaborate more, please? The first question is: "Find an S-box with 3-bit input/output such that $S(x) \not = x$ for every input and also changing each single bit of the input causes at least two bit changes of the output." I think we can't have such an S-box. Do you mean that we can easily design such an S-box?